# Deepcopy list of lists (speed issue)

Tags: python

Due to unclear formulation I decided to rewrite my question:
My code looks sth like this (org is supposed to be a list of a list and two integers):

```
def my_copy(org):
    temp = (tuple(org[0]), org[1], org[2])
    temp2 = []
    temp2.append(list(temp[0]))
    temp2.append(temp[1])
    temp2.append(temp[2])
    return temp2
a = [[1,2,3], 4, 5]
b = []
for i in range(5):
    b.append(my_copy(a))
```

now I can change the elements of b without influencing the others copies. Unlike if I were to use

`b.append(copy.copy(a))`
in the loop

I do all this to avoid using copy.deepcopy() which appears to be quite slow. There are now three questions: Does this code generate a deepcopy of my list? And if not, why does it still create copies and not just new references as  `b.append(a)` would? In addition: How can I do this in a more elegant, fast and pythonic way?

Comment: If you're asking how to make a shallow copy of a list `a`, the answer is `a[:]`.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No, I Need a deep copy :/

Comment: `list(tuple(list(a)))` is not making a deep copy, and if your thing is only a list of integers, you don't need a deep copy anyway.  (Or rather, there is no difference between a shallow and deep copy in that case.)

Comment: hmm, i guess i confuse shallow copy with a = b, which is just appending another tag to the same thing, if that's what you're saying...

Comment: `a = b` is not a copy at all.  A shallow copy just copies the outermost layer: that is, it copies `a` but not what `a` contains.  A deep copy copies everything `a` contains, and everything those things contain, etc.  You only need a deep copy if you have mutable objects inside your container (e.g., a list of lists).

Comment: but isn't an integer a mutable object inside the container? That's sort of why I thought i'd need deepcopy in the first place...

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized why there's a confusion... In my actual code the list that I want to append multiple times is actually a list of lists, containing integers... I have simplified it one step too far

Comment: Integers are immutable. You don't need to copy those.

Comment: If you need it to be deep copied, then `deepcopy` is the way to go.  Your `list(tuple(list(a)))` is not making a deep copy.

Comment: Ok, but if it's not, why is it working, when copy.copy() (shallow copy: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)) isn't?

Comment: @cfrei89: You'll need to show an example of what you're doing with the resulting structure.  From your post right now it's not clear what "working" means.

Comment: Ok:
`a = [[1],[1]];
b = [list(tuple(x)) for x in a];
d[0][0] = 12`
now a is [[1],[1]] and d is [[12][1]]. If it's not a deepcopy why does it work? Is it because I'm actually copying integers which are (as @BrenBarn said) imutable and I'm just iterating over them by using tuple()?

Comment: @cfrei89: That method of copying is not the same as what you describe in your original post.  Please edit your post to show how you are copying your objects and what you're doing with them.

Comment: rewrote the question: I hope it's better that way... I'm terribly sorry if @BrenBarn and the others wasted their time due to my incompetence to write a clear question :/

Comment: @cfrei89 The problem is clearer now. I have updated my answer with an example solution.

Comment: @BrenBarn turns out your very first answer would have been the solution, I just didn't get it. Thx for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be some misunderstanding here of the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy. You state in your question that you are appending lists of lists. Let's assume that the following is such a list:

```
In [32]: x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

In a shallow copy we copy only the first layer. From the docs:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

```
In [33]: z = []

# using the method you describe
In [35]: z.append(list(tuple(list(x))))

In [36]: z
Out[36]: [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

If we now modify the contents of `z` we alter `x`, as we have used a shallow copy.

```
In [38]: z[0][0][0]=7

In [39]: x
Out[39]: [[7, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

In a deep copy, we make a copy of the object at all levels, essentially creating a clone of the original object. From the docs:

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```
In [40]: import copy 

In [41]: z = []

In [42]: x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

In [43]: z.append(copy.deepcopy(x))

In [44]: z
Out[44]: [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]

In [45]: z[0][0][0] = 7

In [46]: x
Out[46]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Numpy is likely the fastest solution to this problem, but you will have to refactor your code to get a benefit. Numpy will not benefit you if you are converting between lists and arrays in the base level of a loop. Instead you should try an vectorise the problem early on and minimize the number of type conversions.

**Edit:**

Looking at the update question, it seems that there is a very simple solution. If the list in your list only ever contains immutable types you can use either of the following:

```
def my_copy_1(org):
    return (copy.copy(org[0]),org[1],org[2])

def my_copy_2(org):
    return (org[0][:],org[1],org[2])
```

Testing the speed on these against your original implementation, I get:

```
In [2]: a = [[1,2,3],1,2]

In [3]: %timeit tmp.my_copy_orig(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit tmp.my_copy_1(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit tmp.my_copy_2(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 784 ns per loop
```

It would appear that `my_copy_2` is the clear winner here in terms of speed. You can test that it produces the correct behaviour with:

```
In [6]: a = [[1,2,3],1,2]

In [7]: z = tmp.my_copy_2(a)

In [8]: z[2] = 999

In [9]: z[0][0] = 999

In [10]: a
Out[10]: [[1, 2, 3], 1, 2]

In [11]: z
Out[11]: [[999, 2, 3], 1, 999]
```